# Windows forms designer froze using Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, freeze

When I open form designer, it freezes - shows a blank page or what was shown before. This is how it looks:

[image: frozen form designer screenshot]

I have `FormMain.cs` [Design] opened, but it shows contents of the tab that was there before (also it causes another issue in solution explorer, but that gets solved when I click anywhere in the solution explorer). I tried deleting the `.suo` file, but it didn't solve the issue.

Also for some reason, I can right-click and lock controls, then unlock and it solves the issue temporarily, when I open another tab and go back to the designer, it's frozen again. It happens only for `FormMain.cs`, the other 2 forms are okay, so I thought it might be something in the designer code - http://pastebin.com/AxTdEbg3 - but even if I delete all the controls from `FormMain.Designer.cs`, it still freezes.

I have Hotfix (KB2635973) and Service Pack 1 (KB983509) for Visual C#, .NET Framework 4 SP1 (but the project uses 3.0). Thanks for all answers, if you need some more information (like the whole project folder), then I'll upload it.

Comment: Do you have any custom loaded controls on your form, or just the ones that come with VS?

Comment: Is there any  code in your FormMain.cs constructor, Load or Paint event?

Comment: No, I'm not using any custom controls, and I override onLoad and onClosing if that could help, but I'm not doing anything with events in the constructor.

Comment: I kinda solved it, I let the .resx file regenerate, it still shows nothing when I go to the designer, but when I click somewhere and redraw it, it works. But still, I'd like to know what's the issue, because it's still not working 100%.